# How can I discover why my machine won't sleep when it is supposed to be?

Tags: windows-7, troubleshooting, sleep

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 PC no longers goes into power saving mode](https://superuser.com/questions/173156/windows-7-pc-no-longers-goes-into-power-saving-mode)

I have a windows 7 x64 machine which is scheduled to go to sleep after a certain amount of inactivity.  Recently it has stopped going to sleep when it is supposed to be.

How can I troubleshoot this and find out what is stopping it going to sleep?

Is there some application I can run which will tell me which app is denying sleep?

Comment: @TomWij, troubleshooting tag? Really?  isn't that [a meta tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)?

Comment: No, then [windows-7] would be one too. The content of the question requests troubleshooting and it doesn't mean different things to different people...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the command `powercfg` (command line) that is available in Vista and Windows 7.
See [this technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd537557.aspx) about troubleshooting power management using the `powercfg` tool.